# EF Core 2.2.6 - Database exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, entity-framework-core

We are using EF Core 2.2.6, with code first approach. We have started to experiance the error: **Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.** This error is happening on **creating the entity** ( not updating the entity ) and it is happening sometimes ( when we have a a lot of threads in parallel). 
This method is used for creating the entity:

```
   public async Task Create(TEntity entity)
        {
            await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

If someone had exeperienced the similiar issue, I would appreciate if you can share with me :)

Comment: Are you by any chance (re)using `_dbContext` from many threads? It's not thread-safe; multiple parallel tasks can't be calling `SaveChangesAsync`.

Comment: I was reviewing my code and it seems I am not re-using _dbContext. I found so far that issue maybe it can be with this line of the code -  await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity); --It should be:-->   await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity); But to keep SaveChangesAsync.